# Regular Expression to match "CP" followed by 3-5 digits

Tags: regex

What will be the regular expression to accept 'CP123' First two letters CP and other 3 or 4 or 5 nos.

Comment: thank you all. 
In CP[0-9]{3,5} it gets CP123 but not accepts CP1 or CP72. I want all these to accept CP123, CP1234, CP1, CP34. 

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CP[0-9]{3,5}
```

Comment: thank you.

In CP[0-9]{3,5} it gets CP123 but not accepts CP1 or CP72. I want all these to accept CP123, CP1234, CP1, CP34. 

Thanks

Comment: here {x,y} defines the min and the max number of [0-9] to be matched. Change x and y to whatever you want.

Comment: If you want the first number to be greater than zero: `CP[1-9][0-9]{2,4}`.

Answer (score 7):

This will match your requirements:

```
^CP\d{3,5}$
```

The ^ matches the beginning of the string, so that it doesn't allow any characters to the left of "CP".

\d matches a digit, {3,5} makes it match 3-5 digits.

The $ matches the end of the string, so that it doesn't allow any characrers after the digits.

If you are using the regular expression in a validation control, you can remove the ^ and $, as that is added by the control:

```
CP\d{3,5}
```

Comment: The only other variation I can think is if the 'CP' should be case insensitive e.g. ^(?i)CP\d{3,5}$

Answer (score 4):

This should work for all regex engines:

```
CP[0-9]{3,5}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per update in comments:

```
CP\d{1,5}
```

if you want one to five digits following CP. Otherwise use

```
CP\d+
```

if you just want CP followed by at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

even if your question it's not very clear this should work:

```
r'^CP[0-9]{3,5}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regxExp = new Regex( "CP[0-9]{3,5}" );
bool result = regxExp.IsMatch( //Expression );
```

Answer (score -3):

```
"$CP123[3-5]^"
```

Comment: I think you switched the $ and the ^.

Comment: as well as misunderstood the question I guess ^^